# Issue number with elsarticle-harv not printed

Tags: natbib, elsarticle

Is it possible to include the issue number, besides the volume number, in article references with \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv} and \usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib}?
Thanks!

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\def\urlprefix{doi: }
\begin{document}
Cite \cite{Zsidisin.2001}
\bibliography{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\end{document}
```

The entry in file References is:

```
@article{Zsidisin.2001,
   author = {Zsidisin, G. A. and Siferd, S. P.},
   title = {Environmental purchasing: a framework for theory development},
   journal = {European Journal of Purchasing \& Supply Management},
   volume = {7},
   number = {1},
   pages = {61-73},
   DOI = {10.1016/S0969-7012(00)00007-1},
   year = {2001},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

And the result I am getting:

[image]

Should I be doing something else/different?

Thanks!

Comment: I have checked and I am using the same version of the bst file.  FUNCTION {article} includes "format.vol.num.pages output" so I should be getting the issue number but it is not happening...? I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that with the latest version of the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style -- version 2.1, dated 2018-06-29 04:55:48Z -- the `number` field of an entry of type `@article` is deliberately no longer printed. To wit, inside the `article` function in the file `elsarticle-harv.bst`, one does find the following line:

```
format.vol.num.pages output
```

Elsewhere in the file, the function `format.vol.num.pages` is defined as follows:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}
```

Essentially, this function first checks if the `volume` field is either empty or duplicate. If that condition is true, the built-in function `skip$` is executed. (You can probably guess what `skip$` does...) If the condition is false, the contents of the `volume` are typeset. Observe that despite the presence of the string "num" in the function's name, `format.vol.num.pages`, the `number` field is *not* processed in any way.

You may quite likely point out that the `pages` field isn't processed either by the `format.vol.num.pages` function shown above. That's indeed true. However, later on in the `article` function, one does come across the line

```
format.journal.pages
```

and you would be correct in assuming that this function processes the contents of the `pages` field in the `@article` entry type.

What to do? You are presumably using the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style because (a) you're preparing to submit a paper to an Elsevier-stable journal and (b) this journal requires you to use just this bibliography style. Since it's the journal's choice how the formatted bibliographic entries are supposed to look like, I would *not* mess about and modify the file `elsarticle-harv.bst`.

Comment: Well, it's for a thesis so I could adapt the style if I knew how. But that's OK - it's not critical. Thanks, Mico!

Comment: @CarlosMartins - If you don't have to use the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style, I wouldn't spend any time editing it. Instead, I would run the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib?lang=en) package, to create a bespoke bibliography style from scratch. The makebst utility is menu-driven, with multiple-choice for each question. The output of the process is a bst file. It's fairly straightforward to use it. For each question, there's a default choice, and for most questions the default answer will do just fine.